# XPath selecting only first level of nodes no matter of their position in hierarchy

Tags: xpath

I have xls data like in below code.
How to select only first level of nodes with class="aaa" attribute?

I can not use something like this "//*[@class='aaa']", becuase it will select also level 2.

Also can not put path directly like "/root/div/div[@class='aaa'], because location of nodes inside hierarchy may be vary.

Is there any way to select only first level of nodes no matter on their position inside hierarchy?

```
<root>
<div>
  <!-- level 1 -->
  <div class="aaa">
    <div>
      <!-- level 2 -->
      <div class="aaa">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>
        <!-- level 2 -->
        <div class="aaa">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <!-- level 1 -->
          <div class="aaa">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible XPath :

```
//div[@class='aaa' and not(ancestor::div[@class='aaa'])]
```

Basically above XPath select `<div>` having `class` equals `"aaa"` and **not having ancestor `<div>` with `class` equals `"aaa"`**, in other words the outer most `<div>` having `class` equals `"aaa"`.

Comment: @johnnyno copy-pasted your html and xpath from this answer to [online XPath tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), this returned 2 `<div>`s as expected, how did you try? Using position index as suggested in the other answer only return the first `<div>` correctly, but not the rest if any..

Comment: It works, but the problem I want to solve is little different. I want to search for elements starting from any node in the hierarchy using dot abbreviation (.//*[@class='aaa' and not(ancestor::*[@class='aaa'])]). It means that your solution works only for root element and if I want to get chidren of first matched child of the root it won't work, because there is always ancestor node matching this part of query not(ancestor::*[@class='aaa']). So in fact can not use this expression not(ancestor::*[@class='aaa']) to filter out ancestors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
.//div[@class='aaa' and not(ancestor::div[@class='aaa']) and not(ancestor::div = self::node())]
```

Comment: Please, consider adding a bit more detail and explanation to your code.